# Missing icons after Win32 to appx conversion

Tags: windows-store-apps, uwp, win-universal-app

I am converting a win32 application to appx using Desktop-app converter. After converting it to appx my application icon is missing and i am unable to pin the application to start. I don't know what went wrong? Can anyone help me to overcome this issue?

Comment: Could you provide more details?  As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell where the problem is. Besides, have you tried to convert any other desktop application like VLC? Does that work on your system?

Comment: The appx is installed but the icon is showing with the default image.

Answer (score 2):

The latest version of the Desktop Application Converter v1.0.6.0 include a new feature to extract the icons, as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-run-desktop-app-converter)

You can always fine tune the images you want to include in your manifest.

Finally, you can use Visual Studio 2017 to generate your visual assets. More information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net).